# UiTest Xamarin Ошибки

Tags: c#, .net, юнит-тесты, тестирование, xamarin.forms

создаю проект UITest в солюшене с проектом Xamarin Forms [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вылезают непонятные ошибки в фале AppInitializer.cs и Tests.cs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом установил сам UiTest и NUnit в пакетах NuGet

Также, почему-то не поддерживаются версии, не знаю как исправить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы вероятно не подключили namespace `Xamarin.UITest` и возможно какие-то ещё

Comment: @KuzCode Я смог исправить все ошибки, кроме несовместимости версий. Не знаете в чем дело? вот скриншот https://prnt.sc/20tjo5u